# Upgrading MySQL with YUM

Tags: linux, mysql, yum

I am trying to upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.7 with yum (using Amazon linux AMI)

When I do :

> sudo yum upgrade mysql

```
No packages marked for update
```

When I do :

> sudo yum install mysql

```
Le paquet mysql-5.5-1.6.amzn1.noarch est déjà installé dans sa dernière version
Rien à faire
```

Question : How do I explain to yum that I want the version 5.7 of MySQL

Comment: what distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using Amazon Linux AMI

Answer (score 0):

there is not a lot of information to go on but there can be a couple of reasons.

- the distro you are using doesn't have the mysql5.7 packages in its repository. You can check the /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder to verify what repositories are currently configured on your server. With `yum info mysql` you can ask some more information about the package available.
- If its an enterprise distro like centos/rhel7 they only go to mysql5.5 (mariadb5.5 actually)
- if u are using the mysql yum repository. They only go by major version (mysql5.5, mysql5.6, mysql5.7) So you would have to install or configure a new repository that has access to mysql5.7. [check here for the mysql yum repo](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/)

Remember that going outside the normal repositories to get a newer version of software could mean you would lose enterprise support. It could technically also introduce problems you wouldn't expect.

My personal experience with mysql5.7 is good though. But i'm always very wary with using software from outside the distro's repositories

Comment: ">yum info mysql"

returns : "Nom                 : mysql
Architecture        : noarch
Version             : 5.5
Révision            : 1.6.amzn1
Taille              : 0.0  
Dépôt               : installed
Depuis le dépôt     : amzn-main"